# Laravel url previous function getting base link instead of previous

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am making use of Laravel 9

This is a very weird issue and I really don't know what could be causing it.
I am trying to implement a 404 error page(`.../errors/404.blade.php`) where I have a link that says `Go back` as in go back to the previous page you came from.

Here is the code I tried:
`<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="link">Go back</a>`

Instead of linking to the previous page, it rather links me to the home page (`127.0.0.1:8000`). Could it be that the `url()` helper function does not work on error pages or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: this depends if there is a referrer header on the request or if it can pull the previous url from the session... if it can not determine what the previous URL is it will fallback to the root of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching far and wide and trying so many things, I discovered that it just does not work on the error page. I even tried routing to another page instead of the previous page but it still linked me to the home page `127.0.0.1:8000`

So the solution I found was to make use of javascript instead. On the link that says `Go Back`, I added a `history.back()` function to it on `click`. Works perfectly and achieves what I desired. So my link now looks like this instead:

`<a onclick="history.back()" href="javascript:void" class="link">Go back</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Never used the `url()->previous();`
but you can try this one. I implemented same thing you are doing in an old site of mine

```
  back()->getTargetUrl();
```

[image]

Comment: same issue. Getting homepage link.

Comment: PS: I am not trying to redirect, just wanna display a link.

Comment: Go to some URL that exists(not homepage), after that change the URL to smth that doesnt exist and try it

Comment: Already tried that, same thing

Comment: dd(back()->getTargetUrl());
in that case do that, without the redirect. Just tested now, it works for me!

Comment: have ```dd()```ed it, gives me ```^ "http://127.0.0.1:8000"```

Comment: please try it on an error 404 page and see if it works for you

Comment: Weird, i edited the question, check the gif above, works well for me

Comment: Wow. This is driving me nuts! Is that an error page you showed above or a casual page?

Comment: If you want u can share the screen or I can login with anydesk to check it

Comment: Is what you shared above an error or a casual page? Because it works fine for me on casual pages, but just not the error page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248512/discussion-between-apollo-and-innovin).